# Editing read-only file on GVim

Tags: vim, vi, macvim

Is there any way to edit read-only file on GVim?

If you use vim on console, `sudo vim /path/to/file` enables you to edit the read-only file. How can I edit it on already-opened MacVim window?

If you open `:tabnew /path/to/file` then edit it, and try to save it, then the error occurs saying `xx is read-only (add ! to override)`. However, when you try to save it by `:w!`, the error still occurs saying `xx Can't open file for reading`.

I know, if you first change the permission of the file and edit it, and then reverts its permission, then you can edit it successfully... But I don't want to bother doing such a tedious thing...

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MacVim comes with `mvim`, a command-line wrapper that allows you to launch the MacVim GUI from the command-line with `$ mvim filename` and the MacVim CLI executable directly in your shell with `$ mvim -v filename`.

Both work well with `sudo` so you can perfectly do `$ sudo mvim filename` to open `filename` with write privileges in a new MacVim Window or `$ sudo mvim --remote filename` to do the same in the current MacVim window.

Comment: When I said `How can I edit it on already-opened MacVim window?`, I mean I want to work on the same window - I knew I could use the CLI to open another file, but it leads to opening yet another window, which is what I'd like to avoid... However, `--remote` option is definitely what I didn't know and it is easier and more intuitive than using `tee`, which I find pretty fascinating. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's ok when I run  `mvim filename`, but it turned out to be `sudo: mvim: command not found` when I run `sudo mvim filename`

Answer (score 3):

Either change the permissions/owner:

```
:!chown myuser %
:!chmod +w %
```

Or write using `sudo` over a pipe:

```
:w !sudo tee %
```

Comment: should add `space` after `:w`

Answer (score 1):

If you find the trick with `tee` too hard to remember / too difficult to type, there's also the [SudoEdit plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2709), which defines a convenient `:SudoWrite` command.

Also see the [Su-write](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Su-write) article on the Vim Tips Wiki.